# How to view ALL Issues (from multiple projects) in a Jira Epic within the Backlog?

Tags: jira

I can look at the Epic itself and view it's child issues, but I'd like be able to view it in the backlog, where I can organize things (add/remove Issues from Epic) with drag'n drop. Guessing it's just not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The Board for that Project filters on only that project by default. If you change the Board filter to include **all projects** it'll show all in the Backlog/Epic view.